# How to make a pure CSS div with a gradient background?

Tags: css, html, gradient

Let's say the height of the div is 34px and the width is 480px.  The div should look like this:

[image]

and I don't want it to actually use an image, just CSS.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is with CSS3. There's even a [handy gradient generator](http://web.archive.org/web/20100825053100/http://gradients.glrzad.com/) which takes the guesswork out of it. Of course, this is completely unsupported in IE8 and under.

---

#### Edit

For the sake of completeness, as [sluukkonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89876/sluukkonen) mentioned, IE does support gradients in CSS using the filter [`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Note that IE _does_ [support gradients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx). Not with CSS3 obviously, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with CSS3;

Example: (black and grey)

```
mydiv
{

   background-image:
        -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.15, rgb(189,189,189)),
        color-stop(0.58, rgb(0,0,0)),
        color-stop(0.79, rgb(0,0,0))
    )
    -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(189,189,189) 15%,
        rgb(0,0,0) 58%,
        rgb(0,0,0) 79%
    )
}
```

But this only works in Mozilla and webkit browsers, IE8 and under will ignore this.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: note: that gets applied to the background-image property, separately.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add that :)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do this with `-webkit-gradient` and `-moz-linear-gradient` 'functions' as values of `background-image`. These use different syntax but will be standardised if the gradient spec makes it into CSS 3's final release.

```
/* webkit example */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)),
  to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#333333)
);
```

```
/* mozilla example - FF3.6+ */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 95%
);
```